# PhpStorm Sass File Watcher template and File Type not available

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I am trying to set up a Sass File Watcher in PhpStorm. But there is no Sass template, as described in the [PhpStorm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/compiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d184063e246). As you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: PhpStorm FileWatchers]

Also, that there is no Sass File Type.

[image: PhpStorm FIle Types]

Answer (score 1):

The Sass support plugin needs to be enabled, in order to be able to use a Sass File Watcher.

Go to **File > Settings > Plugins > write `sass` into the search box > check checkbox next to `Sass support` > click ok and restart PhpStorm**

[image: Sass Plugin]